# Model Mapper Get Null Pointer Exception When Calling Method on Testing Class

Tags: java, spring-boot, dto

When I call the model mapper Entity to DTO converter method I always get null pointer exception.

This is converter service to convert dto to entity and vice versa

I have not deal with DTO previously and this is the first time I use DTO and I also need to know is this the best way I've implemented DTO converter service or if there is any suggestions.

```
@Autowired
private ModelMapper modelMapper;

@Bean
public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
    return new ModelMapper();
}

@Override
public NotificationDto entityToDtoNotification(Notification notification) {
    ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
    return mapper.map(notification, NotificationDto.class);
    
}

@Override
public Notification dtoToEntityNotification(NotificationDto notificationDto) {

    ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
    return mapper.map(notificationDto, Notification.class);

}
```

When I call the method on test calls I get null value

```
class NotificationServiceImplTest {

    @Autowired
    private NotificationServiceImpl notificationService;

    @MockBean
    private NotificationRepository notificationRepository;

    @Autowired
    ConverterServiceImpl converterService;

    @Test
    public void testCreateTicket() {

        Notification notification = new Notification();
        notification.setId(1);
        notification.setMessage("Hello Hashan");


        NotificationDto notificationDto = new NotificationDto();

         
        //I get the null value as return

        notificationDto=converterService.entityToDtoNotification(notification);



        Mockito.when(notificationRepository.save(notification)).thenReturn(notification);
        
        assertThat(notificationService.save(notificationDto)).isEqualTo(notification);

        converterService.entityToDtoNotification(notification);
    }


}
```

Notification Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "notification")
public class Notification {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String message;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public Notification() {
    }

    public Notification(int id, String message) {
        this.id = id;
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

Notification DTO

```
public class NotificationDto {

    private int id;
    private String message;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public NotificationDto(int id, String message) {
        this.id = id;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public NotificationDto() {
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please include codes of NotificationDto and Notification classes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution :
After I added @SpringBootTest annotation on test class I could accesses value from converter service without null pointer exception

```
@SpringBootTest
class NotificationServiceImplTest {
```

Answer (score 1):

You should annotate your test with `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` so that you can autowire the attributes using spring context.

Please see : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.2.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html